# One file to start all services... mongodb, redis, node ,angular and python

Tags: python, node.js, angular, mongodb, redis

Well, my question is. How to create a file which can start node angular, python main_worker.py, MongoDB and redis? I really do not know where to start.

I just wanna start my web program without opening 7 consoles to start each service like python worker angular node and databases.

Answer (score 0):

I know about angular and MongoDB others are not, will it be your help? try the following ways but you need one console

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"mongod\" \"ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --open\" \"tsc -w -p server\" \"nodemon dist/server/app.js\"",
    "prod": "concurrently \"mongod\" \"ng build --aot --prod && tsc -p server && node dist/server/app.js\""    
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docker Compose to start all your services with a single command:

```
docker-compose up
```

Learn more about it here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

You will need to create a docker-compose.yml in your project which will looks something like:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongo
    hostname: mongo
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/var/lib/mongo/data
    networks:
      - your-app-network
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - YOUR_VARIABLE:value
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    image: redis
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - rediso_data:/var/lib/redis/data
    networks:
      - your-app-network
    ports:
      - 6380:6380
    environment:
      - YOUR_VARIABLE:value
volumes:
  mongo_data:
  redis_data:
networks:
  go-app:
    name: your-app-network
```

**Note**, the sample above is not ready to use docker compose file. It just shows you the idea how you do it. You will have to edit it and add some variable and settings specific to your application as well as add more services like node.js, python, etc.

Comment: Please, mark it as an answer and upvote then, so others will see it helps. You are welcome